# Showing "Appendix A with appendix title" and not chapter 1

Tags: numbering, titles, appendices

I'm writing an article and I want to show just the chapter titles at the beginning of them. The problem is with the appendix, since now I'd like to show "Appendix A".

My **main.tex** is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\bfseries\huge}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix} %appendices

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\input{ch1/chapter1}
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{appendices}
\input{app1/appendix1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The beginning of **chapter1.tex** is

```
\chapter{Introduction}
I have some text in this chapter just like this.
It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
essentially unchanged.
```

Part of file **appendix1.tex** is:

```
\chapter{Attached files to the project}
This is a description of the files and images that you will find in the several folders in the DVD.
```

My chapter title is like:

> 1. Introduction

and appendix is:

> A. Attached files to the project

but I'd like to see as appendix title:

> Appendix A
>   Attached files to the project

I know it is related with the command "\titleformat" but how can I fix it in order to show *Appendix A + appendix title*?

Comment: How about getting rid of `\chapter` title and just add appendix manually to toc?

Comment: Yes. But I'd like not to show chapter (1,2,3) for every chapter but only the chapter title. How can I do?

Comment: Providing code with `\input` is never useful, to start with ;-)

Comment: So you don't want the number for the chapter either? I.e. you want `Chapter Title` and not `1. Chapter Title`? Please make your code compilable.

Comment: @cfr  I have updated the question. The main request is the part of the appendix title as I want to show "Appendix A - Appendix title. About the chapter title, I'd like to show '1. Chapter title', but it's not so important that number.

Comment: @Franktrt: What you desire is actually the default by not using `titlesec` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code compile, we need to remove `\maketitle` and the bibliography from the example and integrate the code fragments provided in the question.

Having done that, we can redefine the chapter style within the `appendices` environment to include the `\appendixname` in the chapter label which precedes the title.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\bfseries\huge}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix} %appendices

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
I have some text in this chapter just like this.
It has survived not only
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
essentially unchanged.

\begin{appendices}
  \titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\appendixname{} \thechapter.}{20pt}{\bfseries\huge}
  \chapter{Attached files to the project}
  This is a description of the files and images that you will find in the several folders in the DVD.
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: chapter and appendix]

I gather this is what you want, although I'm not entirely certain.

## EDIT

To put the appendix title on a new line, you can add back the default `display` shape when redefining the format in the `appendices` environment:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge}{\appendixname{} \thechapter.}{20pt}{\bfseries\huge}
```

[image: +display]

Comment: Just one thing. Is it possible to have the title of appendix in a new line?

Comment: @Franktrt Please see edit above. `display` mimics the standard classes' default 'shape' for chapters.